# Trying to append items from Firebase in local function to a global array (array had to be local)

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to append values from Firebase to an array, but it is not appending (and I know this because of the debugger). Firebase is not an issue and nothing else is an issue, just that the values wont append to the global array only because the values are appended in a local function, which for some reason doesn't change the value of the array.

How can I append and actually change the value of my `statData` array (so that the actual appending is local). Please don't ask about Firebase trees or about the efficiency of my code, just please I need help with appending.

Background: I have a collection view and it has 2 labels that will have 2 arrays for values from Firebase

```
var statData = [String]()

...
ref?.child("users").child(user!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            let statret = value?["status"] as? String ?? ""
            self.statData.append(statret)
            self.statData.append(statret)
            self.statData.append(statret)

            // ...
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

To declare your array, if it's an array of `Strings`, you should write:

```
var statData = [String]()
```

This will create and initialize your array as an empty array of `Strings`.

Then I am not sure why you wrote 3 times the same line in your code, but anyway only one time is enough:

```
self.statData.append(statRet)
```

Also, I don't think the problem has something to do with the fact of your array being global, because global or not, you could still append some data to it in a similar fashion.

Another thing here that may be the reason why your array doesn't get filled at all though, is the way you get the data from your database. You could write your code like this instead:

```
// ...

guard userId != nil else {
   return
}

ref?.child("users").child(userId!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

      // ...

      // By using a guard statement here, you make sure that your status child does exist and represents a String. 
      //If not, the return statement will be called. 
      // You may consider adding a break point inside the else statement for debug, if you are still unable to get any data.

      guard let statRet = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "status").value as? String else { return }

      self.statData.append(statRet)

      // ...

})
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same error -> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1058d7b50) when i call -> cell.statsLabel.text = statData[indexPath.row] and add the array's items to the cell. I still think it might be a global issue as appending outside the function is okay. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hmm I see, then please add a breakpoint right before this line and check if statData is empty, it might be the problem here

Comment: Another question for you, where do you add this line ? (cell.statsLabel.text = ...)

Comment: i have a collection view and i stated it in the function:  func collectionView

Comment: also if i append outside the ref function it works...for some reason it's not appending inside this ref function...at the end that number of items in the statData array is 0 if inside the ref function

Comment: Okay! Could you please add the code where you add this line in your question?

Comment: No worries hopefully we will find a solution soon :)

Comment: I have an other question for you (it's better to check everything), could you please show me the structure of your database in the console?

Comment: I'll post the rest of my code soon (I'm in class) but there is no need to see my database b/c the information is being taken out perfectly (I checked by adding the info to the text of a label). the problem is that the append isn't working and the array ends up w/ 0 items

Comment: Okay :) Well it could definitely be helpful to see your database just to make sure the data is at the correct place (not in a child node, etc). I'll think about it anyway ! But please note that it is not possible that appending values to the array doesn't work if the array is properly set, so we need to look up for something else

Comment: As I said in the code's comments of my answer, you should try adding a breakpoint or a print inside the else part of the guard statement. And probably you will see that the else part is being called, which is why the append is not called. If that is the case, that would help us a lot as it would mean that the path for the data is incorrect

Comment: I added a print for the number of items in the array and I got 0

Comment: Nope, I mean, add a print or breakpoint in the else statement of this guard statement :    guard let statRet = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "status").value as? String else { print("something here and check if it appears in the log" ; return }

Comment: i did, and it did not appear in the log

Comment: i set statret = "yup" inside the ref function and it still didn't append. There is a problem with the array. Firebase isn't the issue i don't think. And thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

First off, it would help if you showed where you declared `statData` in your code. Does it look something like this?

```
var statData:[String] = []
```

From there in your firebase handle I suggest explicitly declaring the types of the dictionary as such:

```
let value = snapshot.value as? Dictionary<String,Any>
```

Then grab the `status` value as such:

```
let statret = value[“status”] as? String
```

From there you may append it to your array:

```
self.statData.append(statret)
```

The problem I think you’re having is that it is never actually appending any values because your casts are failing. Let me know if this helps or not.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error -> Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1058d7b50) when i call -> cell.statsLabel.text = statData[indexPath.row] and add the array's items to the cell.